# ListView inside ViewPager with fragment scroll doesnt work

Tags: listview, android-viewpager

I got three tabs and ViewPager to swap between three fragments.
One of these fragment is a ListFragment and it contains ListView.
The problem is that that list isn`t scrollable.

This is MainActivity where i add tabs and ViewPager:

```
private void addTabs() {
    tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setTag("first"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setTag("second"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setTag("third"));

    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    TabsPagerAdapter adapter = new        TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText("Player");
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText("Playlist");
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setText("Songs");
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            // Code goes here
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            // Code goes here
        }
    });

}
```

MainActivity xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/grayCustom"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:background="@color/grayCustom"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"/>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

Playlist class:

```
public class Playlist {

private HashMap<String, Song> playList;
private final Context context;

public Playlist(Context context)
{
    playList = new HashMap<String, Song>();
    this.context = context;

    updatePlayList();
}


private void updatePlayList()
{
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
    Cursor cur = cr.query(uri, null, selection, null, sortOrder);
    int count = 0;

    if(cur != null)
    {
        count = cur.getCount();

        if(count > 0)
        {
            while(cur.moveToNext())
            {
                int id = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String path = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));

                playList.put(name, new Song(id, name, path));
            }
        }
    }
    cur.close();
}

public HashMap<String, Song> getPlayList() {
    return playList;
}
```

}

PlaylistFragment class:

```
public class PlaylistFragment extends ListFragment{

private static final String ARG_PAGE_NUMBER = "page_number";

private static PlaylistFragment mInstance = null;

private Playlist playList;

public static PlaylistFragment getInstance(int page) {
    if(mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new PlaylistFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
        mInstance.setArguments(args);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_playlist, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    initialize();
}

private void initialize()
{
    playList = new Playlist(getActivity());
    ArrayList<String> songsNames = toKeysArray(playList.getPlayList());
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_items, songsNames);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private ArrayList<String> toKeysArray(HashMap<String, Song> playlist)
{
    Set<String> set = playlist.keySet();
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String name : set)
        arr.add(name);
    return arr;
}
```

}

PlaylistFragment xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ofekot.audioplayer.PlaylistFragment">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

TabsPagerAdapter class:

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

```
private int numOfTabs;

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.numOfTabs = numOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            return PlayerFragment.getInstance(position);
        case 1:
            return PlaylistFragment.getInstance(position);
        case 2:
            return SongsFragment.getInstance(position);
        default:
            return SongsFragment.getInstance(position);
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numOfTabs;
}
```

}

I was trying to fix this problem for hours with no luck.
ty

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, it solved by this code:

```
 tabLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    }, 500L);
```